# Need explanation for Cannot insert duplicate key row in object error

Tags: sql, sql-update, key, duplicates, uniqueidentifier

I’m doing:

```
SELECT uid, intStatus from dbo.MYTABLE 
WHERE 
intStatus = 10 and uid = 'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1'
```

And I get:

```
        uid                            |  intStatus 
-------------------------------------- +---------------
'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1  | 10
```

Then I need to do an update, I need the intStatus to be 18 for that uid. So I do:

```
UPDATE dbo.MYTABLE  SET intStatus = 18 
WHERE 
intStatus = 10 and uid = 'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1'
```

And here’s where I’m getting the error:

Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MYTABLE' with unique index 'ixMYTABLE'.

Can anyone, please, tell me why I’m getting this error? How can I solve it?

uid is primary key for MYTABLE

intStatus is a not null int

Thanks a ton!

Comment: There is something in your database design that disallows duplicate values of intStatus in that table, and, there is another record with value 18.  The way to solve it is to find out why duplicates are not being allowed.  There is probably a very good reason.  Then you have to take another look at what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The error states ixMYTABLE unique index. What is the composition of this unique index?

Comment: uid is uniqueidentifier primary key not null and intStatus is an int not null

Comment: Can you post the script for table creation? Please include the index and constrain creation as well.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I'm having the same issue and I can't narrow down to where my PK is being duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have already a row with intStatus 18 and uid 'a1a1...'

Try to run and see if you have already the row that you try to create with your UPDATE:

```
SELECT uid, 
       intStatus 
  FROM dbo.MYTABLE 
 WHERE intStatus = 18 
   AND uid = 'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1'
```

Comment: no rows for intStatus 18 and uid 'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1'

Comment: if uid is the key, you cannot have a duplicated value, even using an update. Unique key means only one row with a given value at any time.

Answer (score 0):

If uid is your primary key then it is unique by definition, therefore the intStatus condition is irrelevant. This should work:

```
UPDATE dbo.MYTABLE  SET intStatus = 18 
WHERE  uid = 'a1a1a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1-a1a1a1a1a1a1';
```

If that doesn't work, then you could have a composite key combining both columns rather than a single column key.

[Info on primary keys and composites](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191236%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

intStatus  is unique
thatswhy mysql throws an error.

if u want to execute that query intStatus should not be unique

Comment: intStatus is an int not null